# Accessing an Angular application from devices from same network

Tags: angular

Well, I'm trying to test a web application built in Angular 12 from my android smartphone or another pc using Chrome or Edge and it seems that the URL is being corrupted in the way from my device to te Angular application. I ran the command below to start the front-end:

> ng serve --host 192.168.1.65 --port 64000 --disable-host-check

and the Angular page is correctly loaded on the browser after address 192.168.1.65:64000 is reached but the request to the backend isn't working. The predefined message that I've wrote to say that something was missing when an unknown error code is returned pops up but I'm writing everything right, e.g.:

> localhost:8080/9.5/94850230/95010003/Miguel

this is the final url created on frontend after all the form fields are filled and send button is clicked. After click the send button the frontend receives an Unknow Error code (out of codes range 400, 500) as an answer. As you can see, the four variables are present in the url, weight (kg), origin zip code (not USA format), destination zip code, receiver name.

Am I trying to test the wrong way?

Can an Angular app to be loaded on browser on a remote machine other than where is the server runnning and works as if the browser were on the same physical machine where the server is located?

Accessing from the same machine where the front-end and back-end are running all works well.

Can someone explain this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Did you configure `proxy-conf.json` so the proxy knows where to forward the requests?

Comment: Hi The Head Rush, no I don't,  I'm not using proxy, thanks!

Comment: That's your problem - you are and you don't know it. The proxy server started by `ng serve` needs to know where to forward the requests.

Comment: requests to localhost go to well, the localhost. a server running on a different machine won't get the requests to localhost on the other machine, unless you configure your network similar to how you did to get your app serving to a different device

Comment: I think your problem is across origin, because you start angular app with host and port 192.168.1.65:64000 and you try to access your backend for this host localhost:8080/9.5/94850230/95010003/Miguel, for solution this you need to set header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true on your backend. if you accessing from the same host you don't have the problem.

Comment: Hi Henry! No, the cross orign is set up on the backend already. I found my mistake, look my own answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found my mistake. The `apiUrl` was written in the frontend code to be:

```
localhost:8080
```

But the correct format is:

```
192.168.1.65:8080
```

So that other devices in the same network can also access the server/backend resource